# FileZilla ETIMEDOUT right after the server was going to start data transfer

Tags: filezilla

So with FileZilla im trying to connect trough an external IP.
From what i see i set up the server correcly, im not so sure about the client tho.
Heres a screenshot: [Data Transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbvOg.png)

I have no idea what to do but help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually is a sign of firewall blocking the ports used by the socket.

Make sure the ports in the "passive range" used by the server are open in the firewall, both in the server and in the client. If it's FileZilla Server you are connecting to, you can use the *Network Configuration Wizard*, accessible via the `Server > Network Configuration Wizard` menu in the *FileZilla Server Administration Interface* to guide you through the configuration process.

For further info on all the nuances of network config during a FTP(S) session, you can read up this guide: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration

Comment: well the windows firewall on the server is disabled so no firewall issues, and what should i change in the network config?

Comment: i put in a new rule on my firewall on the pc im trying to connect to the server, where it makes filezillas passive mode able to use all ports, but that didnt work either (i did choose filezillaclient.exe friom program files, if this is not the right things then ill have to try again)

Comment: filezillaclient.exe is not the server. filezilla-server.exe is the FileZilla Server. Go to https://ftptest.net/ and check whether your server machine is configured correctly.

Comment: it is, i have new issues now, https://superuser.com/questions/1781933/how-do-i-download-all-files-of-a-certain-filetype-txt-in-an-ftp-server-with-c

Comment: @NeatPace so what was the issue, then? If your question has found an answer in my comment, please mark it as the solution. Or else, write the solution yourself and mark it as the solution.