# How do i download all files of a certain filetype (.txt) in an FTP server with cURL?

Tags: command-line, ftp, curl, wildcards

I am trying to download all `.txt` files in an ftp server.
The main usage or mission is to use wildcards, no specific file names.

Download a singular file works with the following command:

```
curl --user user:password "ftp://websiteadress/FileZillaTest.txt" --output FileZillaTest.txt
```

I am trying to download all .txt files in said directory with wildcards (*).
So far this is what I've tried:

```
curl --user user:password "ftp://websiteadress/*.txt" --output *.txt

curl --user user:password "ftp://websiteadress/" --output *.txt
```

It shows the download for a split second, but then comes back with:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

these files do not get downloaded, normally they should be in the System32 folder, like when I download `FileZillaTest.txt` successfully (I have no clue how to send the file to a specific directory, but that is not the main issue at hand.)

Could anybody help me?

Edit: I do indeed connect and the "connection was reset" error happens only sometimes.

I get the same download prompt as when downloading the FileZillaTest.txt, but it does not download.

This is the confusing part, when filezilla downloads it says 100%, this probably means 100% downloaded, yet when I do it for *.txt it stays on 0% and the prompt instantly ends.

UPDATE:

I have been able to successfully download a singular file.

I need to be able to download all `FileZilla(number).txt` files in this location, yet this has been unsuccessful.

the commands to download all files get recognised

`curl --user user:password "ftp://websitename/FileZillaTest002.txt" --output FileZillaTest002.txt`

`curl --user user:password "ftp://websitename/FileZillaTest001.txt" --output FileZillaTest001.txt`

`curl --user user:password "ftp://websitename/FileZillaTest001.txt" --output FileZillaTest*.txt`

`curl --user user:password "ftp://websitename/" --output FileZillaTest*.txt`

I have put these all into a .bat file so I can see which ones work and which ones do not.

these all work except for the last one, it should download all the `FileZilla(number).txt` in that location, but the download is stuck at 0% sadly without error codes.

Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: I don't think curl is the correct tool for this job.   My guess is you would need to write a script to cause it to get a list of files, then iterate through that list.  There are much better tools to use for this job.

Comment: im at my job and my employer gave me this task, unfortunatly i cannot stray from curl.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Using wildcards in wget or curl query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18107344/165358) :

> You can't use wildcards in `wget` but the `-A` flag should work. From
> the [wget manpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):
>
> > You want to download all the gifs from a directory on an http server. You tried `wget http://www.server.com/dir/*.gif`, but that
> > didn't work because http retrieval does not support globbing. In that
> > case, use:  `wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A.gif http://www.server.com/dir/`

In your case, use `-A.txt`.

Comment: i am not using wget tho, i will still try it

Comment: it comes back with curl: (78) The file does not exist

Comment: Please include your wget command in your post. I can look at it in a few hours from now.

Comment: curl --user user:password "ftp://websiteadress/" --output -A.txt

curl --user user:password "ftp://websiteadress/-A.txt" --output *.txt

curl --user user:password "ftp://websiteadress/-A.txt" --output -A.txt

Comment: Try this simpler command : `wget 'ftp://username:password@serverip/dir/*.txt'`