# Trying to download multiple files with curl, files does not exist error

Tags: ftp, download, curl

im having issues with curl again

i am trying to understand https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243134/curl-download-multiple-files-with-brace-syntax

but i do not understand it whatsoever

the issue here is that i am trying to download all files in said directory, or all files that are .txt, both are good.

this is what i am trying:

```
curl --remote-name-all "ftp://user:password@ip/FileZillaTest.txt
curl --remote-name-all "ftp://user:password@ip/.txt
curl --remote-name-all "ftp://user:password@ip/
curl --remote-name-all "ftp://user:password@ip/FileZillaTest
```

yet these all unfortunately have not worked, in this example i have tried

1. downloading all files that have "FileZillaTest" in the name with .txt as extension
2. downloading all .txt files
3. downloading all files in said directory (the wesbite itself goes to the directory)
4. downloading all files that have "FileZillaTest" in the name.

these have all ended in `curl: (78) The file does not exist`

important notice: i cannot individualy do names, this is about 100s of files

wget is unfortunatly not something i can resort to

feel free to ask for more information since i am not sure i havent said enough

Comment: Firstly, this is a repeat: https://superuser.com/questions/1781933/how-do-i-download-all-files-of-a-certain-filetype-txt-in-an-ftp-server-with-c Secondly, your shown commands have invalid syntax with only opening `"`

Comment: @Destroy666: I thought so too in the beginning, but the poster says he can't use wget.

Comment: @Destroy666 that was only for .txt files, and it was about 3, this is about 100s of files including non .txt files.

Comment: the " works just fine in my case, using it without the " gives exactly the same result

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use wildcards which don't exist for curl, and you
say that you can't use wget.

You could use curl to create a list of the files to download:

```
curl -s -l ftp://user:password@ip > urls.txt
```

Then loop on this list.

**For Linux**

The post
[Pass a list of URLs contained in a file to curl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281991/pass-a-list-of-urls-contained-in-a-file-to-curl)
has these suggestions:

```
xargs <urls.txt curl …
curl … $(cat urls.txt)
xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt
```

Or you may use the curl `-K` option which reads from a file of a specific
format. See the
[curl manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-K)
for the format of this file.

**For Windows**

See the post
[Downloading all the files in a directory with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783280/downloading-all-the-files-in-a-directory-with-curl).

Here are some formulations that you might use in a `.bat` file.

A one-line command is :

```
for /f %%f in ('curl -s -l -u user:pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/') do curl -O -u user:pass ftp://ftp.myftpsite.com/%%f
```

If the `curl -l` command results in too many files, do it into
a file and modify the file so as to delete the excess files.
You will then use the
[FOR command](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)
with syntax such as:

```
for %%f in (urls.txt) do curl -O -u user:pass ftp://your_ftp_server_ip/folder/%%f
```

Comment: how do i loop this? im pretty much brand new to this aside from looking up comands and experimenting so terminology is brand new to me. what is "xargs"? or "-s" or "-l"?
so i just make a list of all files (how do i do that for all files, not just .txt)? so bascicaly compile all file names and then run said text file as a command? i dont really understand

Comment: Start with the command which is the simplest, perhaps `xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt`. There are lots of tutorials for `xargs`, for example the first result of google for "xargs tutorial" is [Linux and Unix xargs command tutorial with examples](https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/). See also `man xargs`. Using Linux commands unfortunately requires some study.

Comment: ah sorry i thought it was something under curl, not an alternative like wget, i cannot stray from curl as it was stated so by my employer. sorry, i wish i could make it simpler and take your suggestion but unfortunatly i cannot, i need to use curl.

Comment: xargs is a built-in command into bash, it's not another program that needs installation. You will only be using curl as the program to download.

Comment: so urls.txt will execute every single file in said directory? xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt will then run said file right? how do i get al the 100s of file urls into that txt file?

Comment: By using `curl -l` that lists the files but doesn't download. If it gets too many files, you may need to prune the list.

Comment: can i make a bat files that does: curl.exe, curl -s -l ftp://user:password@ip > urls.txt, xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows ?

Comment: i am usig windows

Comment: My answer is for Linux. I'll add more stuff.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Done. Sorry for assuming Linux, but you gave a Linux link in your post. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign next to it).

Comment: "_`xargs` is a built-in command into bash_" - no it's not, it's a separate but standard executable, for example on my system it's `/usr/bin/xargs`. Check with `type args`

Comment: @roaima: Right, should have written "built-in into Linux".

Comment: ah yes, thanks for that bat file instructions, weirdly when doing so it says "invalid command" when doing the curl command, i suppose this is because it is already in the FTP command? this is the process: https://imgur.com/a/OntorXm

Comment: Curl is program, not an FTP command.

Comment: the exact same thing happens, i do curl;exe since in command line curl only opens when doing curl;exe, then when executing the .bat file it takes the "ftp" from "ftp -i -s:yourscript" as a command to go INTO ftp (not curl) and then execute it there, also your one line command gives this error: %%f was unexpected at this time.

Comment: You might not be specifying the full path to curl.

Comment: i have, but in the .bat file it says "ftp" at the begining, thus going into windows ftp, seeing the "ftp" from said .bat file as the command to start it